# How do I get instances of connected Inlet and Outlet in FlowShape?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

How do I get instances of connected `Inlet` and `Outlet` in `FlowShape` ? Consider following example

```
def throttleFlow[T](rate: FiniteDuration) = Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val ticker = Source.tick(rate, rate, Unit)

  val zip = builder.add(Zip[T, Unit.type])
  val map = Flow[(T, Unit.type)].map { case (value, _) => value }
  val messageExtractor = builder.add(map)

  val in = Inlet[T]("Req.in")
  val out = Outlet[T]("Req.out")

  out ~> zip.in0
  ticker ~> zip.in1
  zip.out ~> messageExtractor.in

  FlowShape.of(in, messageExtractor.out)
})
```

when I use it in `Source.via()` I get following exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: requirement failed: The output port [Req.out] is not part of the underlying graph.
    at scala.Predef$.require(Predef.scala:219)
    at akka.stream.impl.StreamLayout$Module$class.wire(StreamLayout.scala:204)
```

What am I missing ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `in` Inlet and `out` Outlet are not connected to anything. That is why there is an exception (unfortunately this kind of problem can only be detected at runtime)

You want a flow where the only open inlet is one of the zip inlets (`zip.in0`, since `zip.in1` is connected to the ticker), and the only open outlet is the output of the messageExtractor, so how about this:

```
def throttleFlow[T](rate: FiniteDuration) = Flow.fromGraph(GraphDSL.create() { implicit builder =>
  import GraphDSL.Implicits._

  val ticker = Source.tick(rate, rate, ())

  val zip = builder.add(Zip[T, Unit])
  val map = Flow[(T, Unit)].map { case (value, _) => value }
  val messageExtractor = builder.add(map)

  ticker ~> zip.in1
  zip.out ~> messageExtractor.in

  FlowShape.of(zip.in0, messageExtractor.out)
})
```

Comment: Ah I see. So returned FlowShape defines connections. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Just for reference, it compiles and works as expected with Akka 2.4.9. Thanks.